# Unresolved reference : ActivityScenario

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, robolectric

I was just learning how to create tests using **Robolectric**. I was just writing my first Test as following:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class MainActivityTest {

    lateinit var mainActivity: MainActivity

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        mainActivity = setupActivity(MainActivity::class.java)
    }
}
```

But here it shows that `setupActivity` is deprecated and i should use something called **ActivityScenario**. So i tried adding dependencies for it as following:

**Module level build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.unittesting"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1'
    // Core library
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'

    // AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'

    // Assertions
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'

    // Espresso dependencies
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.2.0'

    // The following Espresso dependency can be either "implementation"
    // or "androidTestImplementation", depending on whether you want the
    // dependency to appear on your APK's compile classpath or the test APK
    // classpath.
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.2.0'
}
```

Still i am unable to resolve the class **ActivityScenario**. I don't know what i am missing.

Comment: [`androidx.test:core:1.2.0` has `ActivityScenario`](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/test/core/1.2.0/). However, you are including that dependency for instrumented tests (`androidTestImplementation`), not unit tests (`testImplementation`).

Comment: @CommonsWare Oh my god. How silly mistake it was. Thanks for saving my day.